# In jQuery, how do I access child divs within a cloned div object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I first run this to get my cloned data

```
var cloned = $(".hoverer:first").clone().attr({id: 'id_'+itm_id, class: 'hoverer-active'});
```

That div has a div within it that has an id and class, and that div also has a div in it that has id and class, and I am trying to access the data of the 3rd div?

```
<div id="id_2" class="hoverer-active">
    <div id="sub1" class="test">
        <div id="bus2" class="tset">
            data i want to play with
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `cloned` variable as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) of new jquery commands..

So you can do

```
$('#bus2', cloned).attr('id', newid); // to alter the id if you know the existing one
```

alternatively, since the `cloned` variable holds a jquery object you can use the [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find content inside it..

```
cloned.find('#bus2').attr('id',newid);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the selector for that div within your cloned object. Rembember in jquery when selecting an element you can provide a second parameter that defines the context in which to search.

```
$("#bus2", clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsFiddle with an example : http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/bjNMj/